# Eclipse does not show full project name

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework

I have created a Java project using Play framework. I am using Eclipse IDE . I ran the command `eclipse` in the `play` console to `eclipsify` the project. However, when I import the project in the workbench, it does not show the full project name. The project name is `hellobackend` but it's shown as `hello` only. I tried deleting the project from the workbench and importing it again but it's the same result.

Comment: Look inside `.project` file.

Comment: @AleksandrM I renamed that folder but then Eclipse says the project does not exist. If I import again, it creates another folder in `.projects` directory with the shortened name.

Comment: Folder? Which folder are you talking about?